# Array Formula and nested in-array

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I would like to ask if there is a way to use inner array in array formula. Here's what I would like to achieve:

### 1.) What I have:

#### Pseudo code:

```
MIN{
Array{
if [col T in row N] = 100 AND [col F in row N] = "NO" THAN [col G row N]
if [col T in row N+1] = 100 AND [col F in row N+1] = "NO" THAN [col G row N+1]
...
}
} + 1
```

... where columns T & F & G are of the same size

#### Excel formula:

```
{=MIN(IF( (M38 = INDIRECT(O28)) * (INDIRECT(O32) = "NO"), INDIRECT(O29))) + 1}
```

... where INDIRECT's are pointing to ranges which are of the same size

### 2.) What I want:

#### Pseudo code:

```
MIN{
Array{
if ([col T in row N] = 100 AND [col F in row N] = "NO") AND ([col T in row N] = [col X in row M] AND [col G in row N] != [col Y in row M]) THAN [col G row N]
if ([col T in row N+1] = 100 AND [col F in row N+1] = "NO") AND ([col T in row N+1] = [col X in row M+1] AND [col G in row N+1] != [col Y in row M+1]) THAN [col G row N+1]
...
}
} + 1
```

... where columns T, F, G are of the same size 
... where columns X, Y are of the same size
... where columns T, F, G are **NOT** of the same size as columns X, Y

### MAIN PROBLEM:

Arrays in formula arrays are compute for every row of those arrays and returns array with solution for every row. Is there a way to insert inner formulas with inner arrays which will be computed for every row of outer array?

In advance thank you!

P.S.: I want to use formulas, no VBA please!

Edit 1 - @zaptask Jun 30 at 10:35 :

Thank you for your interest in the matter. I'm including picture with description. I cannot post the file as far as it include company personal data.

[[*Picture LINK*] On left you can see table with references to master table and with few checks about correctness of data comparing them to static variables or to the table itself (so the table with same number of rows). The problem is to compare each record of the left table to every record in right table to see if it is in it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzmRm.png)

Comment: Can you give an exemplary input and output on top of the general description you provided?

Comment: @zaptask I added an image with description. I hope this will make clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: Look into named formulas. I think its always a good start when you have components which can b calculated separately.

Comment: @pnuts differently said if array formulas iterate over table when they calculate formula for every row in iteration and then output array of the solutions for every row I want to put in such a formula another array formula that would calculate another formula for another whole table and supply its output array to every iteration of first array formula for computation in every row.
So create nested loop effect.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring all but:

> compare each record of the left table to every record in right table

and then guessing, the following might suit:

```
=COUNTIF(Restricted_IP,New_IP)
```

when copied down.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't solve my problem. I am looking for a way how to execute two iterations over two different (in size) tables using arrays formulas in one formula in one cell. Where first outer formula will iterate over bigger table and second formula will iterate over different size table and supply its array output to every iteration of first outer array formula.
When I am speaking of "iteration" i mean functionality of array formulas to first count the formula for every row in range in them and than output array of all calculations.
I have one array formula but I can't nest another